# Vim: open assuming certain file type/syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

How would you open vim with a command that makes it highlight as it highlights markdown files (.md)

I am not trying to actually edit a .md file

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line?

```
vim +'set ft=markdown' file
```

Comment: @Rojo I'm happy that I could help you! You should checkout `man vim` for more awesome command line options :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the file type manually:

```
:set filetype=markdown
```

(Or `:set ft=markdown` if you're too lazy to type the whole thing.)

Comment: Thanks, +1. This would have been enough if I had also known that you could run `vim +'...'` to start it from the command line!